# Does my visa name have to match my name on my passport to enter the US

Tags: visas, usa, customs-and-immigration

I recently just obtained my visa to enter the US. I'm a Mexican with a Mexican passport. My name on my passport is as follows:
First Name: Maria
Second Name: de Lourdes.

My name on my visa is:
First Name: Maria
Second Name: Lourdes.

My question is if I will have trouble entering the US because one says "Maria de Lourdes" and the other document says, "Maria Lourdes". The last names appear the same, my issue is only with the 2nd name.

Comment: can you direct me were i can't find the question